# The hairy ball theorem, from Brouwer's fixed point.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

**EDIT :** The question is now the following. I know this statement of the hairy ball theorem :

**Theorem :** Let $n \geq 3$ be an odd number, and $f:\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous map such that $\langle f(x),x \rangle = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

In the linked paper provided by C.F.G., there is this version of hairy ball theorem :

**Theorem :** For any continuous map $v : B \rightarrow R^n$ such that $\langle v(x), x \rangle \leq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, there
exists some $z \in B$ such that $v(z)=0$.

To be honest, I don't really see how to go from one of these versions to the other : how the even dimension is replaced, in the second version, by the hypothesis $\langle v(x), x \rangle \leq 0$ ? Is someone could explain how these two statements are linked, that would be great !

$$-------------------------------------$$

**Original question :**

My question is rather simple today : is there an easy proof of hairy ball theorem that uses Brouwer fixed point theorem ?

I know that these two results are similar in some ways, and I know that they have proofs that rely on the same kind of arguments (I saw Milnor proofs for these two results), but my concern is : let's suppose that you know that Brouwer's fixed point theorem is true ; is there a way to deduce the hairy ball theorem with only elementary steps from there ?

I guess there may be an obstruction, due to the fact that Brouwer theorem is true in every dimension, whereas the hairy ball theorem is not.

If someone knows a short proof, or has a reference, it would be really nice.

Thanks !

Comment: What is your definition of "hairy ball theorem"? is that means its Euler char is not zero?

Comment: @C.F.G It may be equivalent, but the statement I have in mind is the following : "if $n \geq 3$ is an odd number, and $f : \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous map such that $ \langle f(x),x \rangle=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ such that $f(x_0)=0$."

Answer (score 2):

You can find a proof of this fact in the appendix of

*Penot, Jean-Paul*, [**Analysis. From concepts to applications**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-32411-1), Universitext. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-32409-8/pbk; 978-3-319-32411-1/ebook). xxiii, 669 p. (2016). [ZBL1366.26002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1366.26002).

that [is accessible freely in publisher website](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-319-32411-1%2F1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I looked for. There is just one thing that bothers me : the given statement of the hairy ball theorem is not the exact same as the one I gave, the hypothesis on the dimension is replaced in the paper by the hypothesis $x.v(x) \leq 0$. And I don't really see how to go from one to the other... Could you please explain the links between these two statements, and why they are equivalent ? Thanks again for your help !

Comment: I also want to know where in the theorem the even dimension has been used!

Comment: Haha, ok :) Thanks for your help, and I edited the question, I hope someone can clarify this !

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say I can't provide a proof that Brouwer's fixed point theorem implies the hairy sphere theorem, or vice versa. But I do have a few comments you could find helpful.
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\renewcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}}$

**Where the confusion comes from.** What you're calling the "hairy ball theorem" is actually the "hairy sphere theorem". Notice that it only involves a sphere and not a ball. The paper linked in C.F.G.'s answer is about the hairy ball theorem, which is not the theorem you seek. This is probably the main source of confusion.

**An easy implication.** You can prove the following:
\begin{align}
& \text{There's no "combing" of } \S^n \\
& \Longrightarrow \quad 
\text{There's no "combing" of } B^n \\
& \Longrightarrow \quad 
\text{Every map } B^n \to B^n \text{ has a fixed point.}
\end{align}
The second implication is actually an equivalence, as shown in the paper linked by C.F.G. The first implication is outlined below. Beware that the first assertion only holds for even $n$, so the implication is not as useful as it might be. However, there is another easy implication:
$$
\text{Every map } B^{n+1} \to B^{n+1} \text{ has a fixed pt}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad 
\text{Every map } B^n \to B^n \text{ has a fixed pt}
$$
obtained by considering the function $F(x_0,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}) = (f(x_1,\ldots,x_n),0)$. Thus, we have a full proof that the hairy sphere theorem implies Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

*Edit.* After writing the sketch of proof below, I noticed that the same thing is proved on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#A_proof_using_the_hairy_ball_theorem), although the construction there is (I think) different.

---

*Proof (a sketch of).* Assume that there is a combing of $B^n$, i.e. a continuous map $v \colon B^n \to \R^n$ satisfying $v(x) \cdot x \le 0$ on the boundary. We can modify $v$ so that $v(x) = -x$ on the boundary. To this end, consider $w(s,x) := s \cdot v(x) + (1-s) \cdot (-x)$ and take $\tilde{v}(x) := w(s(x), x)$ with $s$ dependent on $x$ as follows:

- $s = 0$ on the boundary
- $s = 1$ on most of the ball
- $0 < s < 1$ on a small neighborhood of the boundary, changing continuously

so that the resulting vector field $\tilde{v}$ is still non-vanishing (this is possible thanks to $v(x) \cdot x \le 0$ on the boundary).

As a next step, notice that the ball is diffeomorphic to the half-sphere $\S^n_+ = \S^n \cap \{ x_0 \geq 0 \}$, which has the equator $E = \S^n \cap \{ x_0 = 0 \}$ as its boundary. By the previous step, we can have nonvanishing tangent field $v_+$ on $\S^n_+$ satisfying $v_+(x) = (1,0,0,\ldots)$ for $x \in E$. Now, by a reflection we can produce a similar nonvanishing tangent field $v_-$ on $\S^n_-$, which satisfies $v_-(x) = -v_+(x)$ for $x \in E$. Finally, taking
$$
v(x) := 
\begin{cases}
v_+(x) & \text{for } x \in \S^n_+, \\
-v_-(x) & \text{for } x \in \S^n_-,
\end{cases}
$$
we obtain a nonvanishing tangent field on $\S^n$.